# Android Parcelable in Kotlin: CREATOR not found on Parcelable data class

Tags: android, parcelable, kotlin, parcel

With the release of the Kotlin RC, I started writing an app to learn it however I can not figure out how to get `Parcelable` to work.

the data class:

```
data class Project (val reponame:String,
                val username:String,
                val language:String,
                val vcsUrl:String,
                val branches:Map<String, Branch>) : Parcelable {

    companion object {
        val CREATOR = object : Parcelable.Creator<Project> {
            override fun createFromParcel(`in`: Parcel): Project {
                return Project(`in`)
            }

            override fun newArray(size: Int): Array<Project?> {
                return arrayOfNulls(size)
            }
        }
    }

    protected constructor(parcelIn: Parcel) : this (
            parcelIn.readString(),
            parcelIn.readString(),
            parcelIn.readString(),
            parcelIn.readString(),
            mapOf<String, Branch>().apply {
                parcelIn.readMap(this, Branch::class.java.classLoader)
            }
    )

    override fun describeContents(): Int {
        throw UnsupportedOperationException()
    }

    override fun writeToParcel(dest: Parcel, flags: Int) {
        dest.writeString(reponame)
        dest.writeString(username)
        dest.writeString(language)
        dest.writeString(vcsUrl)
        dest.writeMap(branches)
    }

}
```

Reading it:

```
class ProjectDetailActivity : BaseActivity() {

    lateinit var project: Project

    companion object {
        const val EXTRA_PROJECT = "extra_project"
    }

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        project = intent.extras.getParcelable(EXTRA_PROJECT)

        tvTitle.text = project.reponame
    }
}
```

The exception:

```
Caused by: android.os.BadParcelableException: Parcelable protocol requires a Parcelable.Creator object called CREATOR on class com.eggman.circleciandroid.model.Project
    at android.os.Parcel.readParcelableCreator(Parcel.java:2415)
    at android.os.Parcel.readParcelable(Parcel.java:2337)
    at android.os.Parcel.readValue(Parcel.java:2243)
    at android.os.Parcel.readArrayMapInternal(Parcel.java:2592)
    at android.os.BaseBundle.unparcel(BaseBundle.java:221)
    at android.os.BaseBundle.get(BaseBundle.java:281)
    at com.eggman.circleciandroid.ui.ProjectDetailActivity.onCreate(ProjectDetailActivity.kt:22)
```

I am sure it is something simple I am missing, has anyone else had success with Parcelable on latest Kotlin?

Kotlin Version: 1.0.0-rc-1036

Kotlin Plugin Version: 1.0.0-rc-1036-IJ143-4

Code is viewable @ https://github.com/eggman87/circle-kotlin

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Kotlin RC dropped previously deprecated generation of static fields for all companion object properties (learn more in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35119082/2196460)).

Now only those marked by `const`, `lateinit` or `@JvmField` will have a static field generated.

You need to annotate `val CREATOR` by `@JvmField` annotation since Android Framework expects a static field `CREATOR` in your class.

Comment: In this case the problem seems to be in the way you are getting the *EXTRA_PROJECT*, just call intent.extras.get(EXTRA_PROJECT) but the problem is not in the Parcelable definition, you don't need to add this.

Comment: @juancho, I agree that, possibly, some other way of working with `Parcelable` wouldn't cause the problem in OP (and I could not even reproduce it). But the exception there is definitely thrown because of the missing static field, and the answer resolves it. That's why I decided to undelete it. Could you please reproduce the problem and check if this solves it? If it does, I think, it would be a better answer.

Comment: I clone and test the project and yes it's regarding this JvmField. I'm a little confuse why I'm not facing the same issue in my project. Also I tried to get the same error in my project but nothing. I'll delete my comments just to avoid confusions. Thanks :) !

Comment: also for parcelable implementation, @JvmField is not enough, you also need @Suppress("unused"). In my case it wouldn't start without it and I would still had the crash

Comment: @PopTudor the suppress statement is only to avoid compiler warnings, should not have any impact on a crash.

Comment: Is that perhaps fixed meanwhile?

Answer (score 1):

Here you have some useful Kotlin extension functions that will help you to create your `CREATOR`s and also some examples (using data classes and list inside the data class)

[Gist: Data Class & Parcelables example](https://gist.github.com/juanchosaravia/0b61204551d4ec815bbf)

I'm using this code in an Android App: [(link)](https://github.com/juanchosaravia/Keddit)

The same code you can find it here: [(link)](https://github.com/juanchosaravia/Keddit/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/droidcba/keddit/commons/Models.kt)

Comment: This code most probably will fail for the same reason if compiled with Kotlin RC (because of `val CREATOR` not being static anymore). Did you check it?

Comment: I'm using it in my app with the RC. Did you tried it?

Comment: Ok, I'll check it shortly.

Comment: Well, it works. Given that, can you state what's wrong in code in the question?

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I updated my code to follow the same pattern but I am still getting the BadParcelableException when reading. Updated class: https://github.com/eggman87/circle-kotlin/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/eggman/circleciandroid/model/Project.kt

Comment: @hotkey your answer resolves the issue - thanks for the link with more info. Marked it as correct. Thanks everyone.