# What is a Companion Object and why do we need it?

Tags: kotlin

I am currently learning the Kotlin language.

I want to know what is a Companion Object, and why do we need it?

I think there is a similar concept in Scala.

Comment: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/object-declarations.html#companion-objects

Comment: I don't see how this question asks to recommend an off-site resource. However, this is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38381748/why-do-we-use-companion-object-as-a-kind-of-replacement-for-java-static-fields and should be closed as such.

Comment: https://twitter.com/anupcowkur/status/809609624278007810

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Members of the companion object can be called by using simply the class name as the qualifier

like a java static

if  called Anothrer class's member variable or method
you use that companion object