# kotlin const val Const 'val' are only allowed on top level or in objects

Tags: kotlin

In my Kotlin project I want to declare constant on compile time:

So I use this:

```
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4::class)
class TradersActivityTest {

    private lateinit var mockServer: MockWebServer
    private const val ONE_TR = "no_wallets.json" // error here
```

But I has compile time error:

```
Const 'val' are only allowed on top level or in objects
```

How declare compile time constant?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @marstran How declare compile time constant?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

`const val`s cannot be in a class. For you, this means you need to declare it top-level, in an object, or in a companion object (which also is exactly what the error message says).

Since your value is private, a `companion object` is one of the two options you can use:

```
class TradersActivityTest {
    ...
    companion object {
        private const val ONE_TR = "no_wallets.json"
    }
}
```

Doing that makes it accessible to the class only.

---

The second option is top-level. However, note that this exposes it to the rest of the file, not just the one class:

```
private const val ONE_TR = "no_wallets.json"

...

class TradersActivityTest {
    ...
}
```

---

For the sake of completeness, the third option was using an object:

```
object Constants {
    const val ONE_TR = "no_wallets.json"
}
```

However, it needs to be public to be accessed. It can alternatively be internal, but it again depends on what you want to have access.

Comment: "companion object" - is a analog of static in Java ?

Comment: @Alex yes and no. A companion object is technically a singleton in terms of Java interop (if you've called a companion object from Kotlin, you might've noticed the syntax is `SomeClassName.COMPANION.someField`. They act static, but not in the "traditional" way as with Java. See [the docs](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/object-declarations.html#companion-objects), or even better, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38382433/6296561).

Comment: Why const is not allowed in a class ?? Why is it allowed only inside object or companion object or top level ?? Is there any reason for that ??